# what is the efficient way to populate state spinner according to country spinner

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [dynamic spinners state/city](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078654/dynamic-spinners-state-city)

i am new to android. i am learning the basic concepts.

Right now i am trying to develop an application which asks the

1:name(EditText)

2:number(EditText). upto that i had done.

3:after that i want user to select a country(Spinner).

4: Once a country is selected, i want to populate my state(Spinner) according to selected country.

I did not want to save those details, i just want to give an alert with all input details.

now, how can i efficiently do that task. do i need to use SQLite, or anything else?

Plz suggest an efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to show only data, I don't think you need a SQLite database,etc. But you have to have a relationship with Country and State in-order to achieve your requirement.
So first try to load Spinner with java.util.List of java.util.Map (Ex: every Country has a name & a code).[check this link](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/12/android-spinners-simpleadapter-and-maybe-viewbinder/)

Comment: Thank you very much dear. i was waiting for a reply.

Comment: Rakhita, thanks for ur reply.

But how can i create multilevel hashmap?
and how i can use that for my need?
can u plz breif with code. it will be more helpful to me rather than searching new

Comment: please check the link I posted... it has the basic idea of getting a List of Map objects to a List...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078654/dynamic-spinners-state-city