# Android Spinners, changing Adapters

Tags: android

Alright, so I'm new to Android programming, so far my experience has been quite interesting and challenging. But I fear I have now encountered the first problem I'm not able to overcome on my own.

Simply put, all I want to do is have 2 Spinners:
1 for country selection
1 for province/state selection

What I want to accomplish is that when the user selects his/her country the province/state Spinner is updated with the correct adapter. Currently I'm only using 2 country for testing purposes.

When I launch the Activity, I get an exception and my app crashes.

Here's my code, any pointers would be appreciated !

```
    public class ManageAccountActivity extends Activity {

    final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSexe = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(ManageAccountActivity.this, R.array.sex_array_fr, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterProvince = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(ManageAccountActivity.this, R.array.province_array_fr, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterStates = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(ManageAccountActivity.this, R.array.state_array_fr, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterCountry = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(ManageAccountActivity.this, R.array.country_array_fr, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.account_management);

        Spinner spinSexe = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_sex);
        Spinner spinProvince = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_province);
        Spinner spinCountry = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_country);

        adapterSexe.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapterProvince.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapterStates.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapterCountry.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinSexe.setAdapter(adapterSexe);
        spinProvince.setAdapter(adapterProvince);
        spinCountry.setAdapter(adapterCountry);

        spinCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CountryOnItemSelectedListener());   
    }   

    public class CountryOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            setContentView(R.layout.account_management);
            Spinner spinProvince = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spin_province);

            if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("Canada")) {
                spinProvince.setAdapter(adapterProvince);
            } else {
                spinProvince.setAdapter(adapterStates);
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
          // Do nothing.
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the LogCat message I'm getting.

> 01-10 20:41:01.024: E/AndroidRuntime(1275):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{gggolf.android.minutegolf/gggolf.android.minutegolf.ManageAccountActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Here is link with similar requirement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078654/dynamic-multiple-spinners-state-city

Comment: That logcat extract doesn't explain anything other than you have a NullPointerException. You need to look at which line is causing it. By the way, using `setContentView` in the listener shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Check AndroidManifest.xml. Did you declare ManageAccountActivity there?

Comment: @MisterSquonk Alright, I've removed it!

Comment: @Maxim It is indeed declared, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot instantiate your ArrayAdapter directly on class attribut, because createFromResource() use Context, and it's not exists at this time, do it in onCreate() methode instead.

In addition, you get *spin province* wrong in your listener, you can't call findViewById on *view* local variable, because it's not your layout, but an inflate of android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item

The good way:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        Spinner spinProvince = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_province);

        if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("Canada")) {
            spinProvince.setAdapter(adapterProvince);
        } else {
            spinProvince.setAdapter(adapterStates);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Last thing, as [MisterSquonk](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8810900/1014291) said, you can make your code simpler, by implement OnItemSelectedListener directly on your activity.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have `setContentView(R.layout.account_management);` in your `onItemSelected()` method? That should not be necessary.

Furthermore, you should instantiate your adapters in the `onCreate()` method of your activity, and pass your actual activity instance as the context.

And the code for retrieving the Spinner object in the select listener should be changed from

```
Spinner spinProvince = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spin_province);
```

into

```
Spinner spinProvince = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_province);
```

Calling `findViewById()` on the local view object in your select listener will return NULL because the view does not contain the Spinner.

Answer (score 1):

Try having your `Activity` implement `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` itself. Notice I've moved the `Spinners` and left out some of your code and replaced it with comments - make sure you include it where necessary...

```
public class ManageAccountActivity extends Activity
    implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    // Your ArrayAdapters as before

    Spinner spinSexe = null;
    Spinner spinProvince = null;
    Spinner spinCountry = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.account_management);

        spinSexe = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_sex);
        spinProvince = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_province);
        spinCountry = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_country);

        // Call setDropDownViewResource on your ArrayAdapters

        // Call setAdapter on your Spinners

        spinCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);   
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

        if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("Canada")) {
            spinProvince.setAdapter(adapterProvince);
        } else {
            spinProvince.setAdapter(adapterStates);
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {

    }
}
```