# android database and spinner

Tags: android, database, sqlite, spinner

I have three spinners populated from database.

**table 1(spinner 1)**

*1* staff
*2* student
*3* subjects

**table 2(spinner 2)**

*1*   1   raja(staff)
*1*   2   stephen(staff)
*1*   3   mohammed(staff)
*2*   4   ben(student)
*2*   5   parker(student)
*3*   6   english(subjects)
*3*   7   science(subjects)
*3*   8   history(subjects)

**table 3(spinner 3)**

1   tall(raja)
1   white(raja)
2   short(stephen)
2   white(stephen)

The project is briefed as simple as below,

In this, every spinner has its own table(eg table1 for spinner1 etc...). Here every word has its own id(eg 1 staff. in this "1" is the id for staff). based on this id the spinners are related. It is that, from spinner1, if staff is selected then  raja, stephen, mohammed should be displayed in the second spinner. Likewise if stephen is selected in the second spinner then tall, white should be displayed in the third spinner. I don't know how to do it. Help me in creating database(parsed from XML feed), and populating in the spinners from the database... also your suggestions pls...

Guys please help me. I'm totally stuck. pls...

Comment: you want to display second spinner data depending upon selection of first spinner am i right?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078654/dynamic-multiple-spinners-state-city

Answer (score 3):

1. retrieve data data for spinner1 i.e. data from table 1 display it on spinner.
2. [setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener l)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29) of spinner retrive data from database depending upon selection of first spinner data add that data to spinner by [public void setAdapter (SpinnerAdapter adapter)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.SpinnerAdapter%29) after u set adapter call [public void notifyDataSetChanged ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)
3. repeat same for second spinner selection