# Android spinners populate with data

Tags: android

I have three spinners in my activity. based on the item selected in first spinner the second spinner is populated with a new set of values. till here the program works fine. now i want that based on selection of item on 2nd spinner the third spinner should be populated. but i am not able to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

As you can do on the first spinner and second spinner. use `secondSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()` and then create and setAdapter to the third spinner.

see  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078654/dynamic-multiple-spinners-state-city) might help

Comment: Actually i am calling a new java class filefrom on item selected listener of second spinner. And in the new java file iam not able yo get a reference of my first spinner and thirs spinner